# Hamburger Transitions not working in react and onClick event too

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The aim of my game - to get a hamburger icon to show transition to a cross on click, then when clicked again to revert back to its burger state. But I don't know why it's not working please help!!

I want that my hamburger should show my given transition when I click on it.

App.JSX File

```
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar/navbar";
import Intro from "./Components/Intro/intro";
import About from "./Components/About/about";
import Skills from "./Components/Skills/skill";
import Portfolio from "./Components/portfolio/portfolio";
import Contact from "./Components/Contact/contact";
import "./app.scss";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [menuopen, setMenuOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {/* //Component Calling */}
      <div className="navbar">
        {" "}
        <Navbar menuopen={menuopen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen} />
      </div>

      <div className="sections">
        <Intro />
        <About />
        <Skills />
        <Portfolio />
        <Contact />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

navbar.jsx

```
import "./navbar.scss";
import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";

export default function navbar({ menuopen, setMenuOpen }) {
  return (
    <div className={"navbar" + (menuopen && "active")}>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="left">
          <a href="#intro" className="logo">
            nishant.
          </a>
          <div className="itemContainer">
            <PersonIcon className="icon" />
            <span>+91 6386 694 7041</span>
          </div>
          <div className="itemContainer">
            <MailIcon className="icon" />
            <span>yadavnishant995@gmail.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <div className="hamburger " onClick={() => setMenuOpen(!menuopen)}>
            <span className="line 1"></span>
            <span className="line 2"></span>
            <span className="line 3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

navbar.scss

```
@import "../../global.scss";

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  color: $mainColor;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: all 1s ease;

  .wrapper {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .left {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;

      .logo {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
        margin-right: 40px;
      }

      .itemContainer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-left: 30px;

        .icon {
          font-size: 18px;
          margin-right: 5px;
        }

        span {
          font-size: 15px;
          font-weight: 500;
        }
      }
    }

    .right {
      .hamburger {
        width: 32px;
        height: 25px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        cursor: pointer;

        span {
          width: 100%;
          height: 3px;
          background-color: $mainColor;
          transform-origin: left;
          transition: all 2s ease;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.active {
    background-color: $mainColor;
    color: white;

    .hamburger {
      span {
        &:first-child {
          background-color: white;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        &:last-child {
          background-color: white;
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but there is no space between the class names `"navbar" + (menuopen && "active")`.

Comment: No that's not a problem

Comment: Github repo link of this project - [link] (https://github.com/yadavNishant2020/portfolio-reactJs)

Comment: Since you have HTML, CSS and Javascript, could you please provide a live example with jsFiddle or Codepen?

Answer (score 0):

As as said, it would be easier to understand your code with a live example, but I suspect it doesn't work because of this:

```
<div className={"navbar" + (menuopen && "active")}>
```

When `menuopen` is `false`, the className is: `"navbarfalse"`.
When it's `true`, it becomes: `"navbaractive"`

You obviously need a space after `navbar`. I recommend you to write instead:

```
<div className={`navbar ${menuopen ? "active" : ""}`}>
```